# Global lock and wait if something true

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have an issue where my API receives a ColumnId from outside (its purpose is to do some updates in the database). However, if two requests with the same Id try to access it, I receive an error because two transactions can't be executed over the same row.

Since I still need to execute both nonetheless, is there a way to make a Singleton or a static class that will handle these HTTP requests so that if two requests with the same ColumnId get sent to the API, the API executes the first one and then executes the second one?

```cs
public MyClass DoStuff(MyClass2 obj, HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    MyClass test = new MyClass();
    // .Create() creates a session with the database
    using (var sc = _sessionManager.Create())
    {
        try 
        {
            var anotherObj = _repository.FindForUpdate(obj.Id);

            //modify anotherObj, save it to the database and set some values for `test` based on anotherObj
        }
        catch
        {
            sc.Rollback();
        }
    }
    return test;
}
```

`FindForUpdate` executes a query similar to this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @Id FOR UPDATE
```

The best I can think of is to have a singleton (as stated above) that will queue and lock the `using statement` in `DoStuff` if the Id is the same, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: Don't forget to consider how any solution you find scales if your application is/might one day be load balanced over several servers.

Comment: I did not share the actual code because it ain't mine, but I 'rephrased' it so that it refers to the same.

Answer (score 0):

It should be quite straightforward to implement a global lock either in a static class or in a class defined with a singleton lifetime in your IoC container. You could use the `lock` keyword for this, or one of the many other synchronization primitives offered by .Net such as the `SemaphoreSlim` class.

However, as pointed out by John, this scales poorly to multiple web servers, and doesn't leverage the concurrency mechanisms offered by the database. It's hard to give concrete recommendations without knowing the specifics of your database platform and data access framework, but you should probably look into either using `FOR UPDATE WAIT` if your database supports it, or just an optimistic concurrency mechanism with some retry logic in your application for reapplying the update after waiting a short while.

Ideally, you will also want to change any long-running blocking operations in your application to use `async/await`, so that the web server thread is released back to the threadpool for serving other requests.

Comment: If I use the `lock`, then the second request that tries to access the same will be refused, won't it? Plus, I need to lock it only if there's a request that's currently being executed / handled that contains the same value for that `Id`.

Comment: `lock` will block until the supplied object is released by the other thread, it will not fail immediately.

Comment: Ah I see, but I can't do it based on an `if statement` because I want to lock only the resources with the same `obj.Id`. Other requests should pass normally. So, if 3 requests come and have their `obj.Id` as `2,2,4`, I wanna wait for the first one to finish before the second gets handled at all, but `lock` probably doesn't provide me with queueing options.

Comment: It could be done with multiple lock objects, but that's tricky and another reason to go for a mechanism in the database. Which one are you using?

Comment: I suppose `Semaphore` or `SemaphoreSlim` wouldn't do the trick? As for the database, I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: I was under the impression that PostgreSQL waited by default when using FOR UPDATE, rather than failing, are you using NOWAIT?

Comment: No, I am not using `NOWAIT`.

Comment: What version of Postgres?

Comment: The version is 9.3.23.

Comment: That should support waiting when using FOR UPDATE...strange https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/sql-select.html